# Fatal error: Call to a member function isError() on a non-object... What's the cause?

Tags: php, error-handling

I moved from another server to a new one, and now started getting this error in a script. The only reason I can think, is due to some php configuration or version.

Any idea?
I can't be a code error, as on the other server this error didn't appear.

Comment: We're not mind readers. Show us some code.

Comment: Are you using PEAR? If so, it might not be installed

Comment: Do the two server have different php version?

Comment: Yes. The server where the code works is PHP Version 5.3.8 and the other where gets fatal error, 5.3.23